# How is SSE (Server-Sent Events) `retry` option supposed to work?

Tags: server-sent-events

When sending SSE message from a server there is a parameter `retry` that can be put into a message. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#fields).

> The reconnection time to use when attempting to send the event. This must be an integer, specifying the reconnection time in milliseconds. If a non-integer value is specified, the field is ignored.

But I actually can not get what is it about. Can someone clarify what is this parameter for how it is supposed to work? I don't get what it is for and who (server or client?) is supposed to use it, and what for?

Answer (score 2):

It’s a client instruction: the browser will wait the specified time after it detects a broken connection (because the server closes the connection after a message perhaps) before re-establishing a connection to the SSE resource url.

Comment: but can the server force to close the connection? as far as i know only if an error is returned at some point

Comment: The server can always terminate a connection at the server end. You would have to create an event that asks the client to terminate - that is no longer listen to SSE on a path, and the client would have to act on it. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are missing a newline after the retry. This should work(PHP):

```
echo "retry: 10000\n\n"; // wait for 10 seconds
```